# How can I more efficiently call replaceAll twice on a single string

Tags: java, regex, string, compilation, replaceall

I currently want to do this all in one line:

```
String output = Pattern.compile("(\\r|\\n|\\t)").matcher(obj).replaceAll("");
Pattern.compile("[^\\p{Print}]").matcher(output).replaceAll(replacement);
```

But I am unable to do the following:

```
Pattern.compile("(\\r|\\n|\\t)").matcher(obj).replaceAll("").Pattern.compile("[^\\p{Print}]").matcher(output).replaceAll(replacement);
```

How can I make it so that the second regex is also compiled at the same time?

Comment: Putting things on the same line doesn't mean they happen at the same time, or more efficiently. Each thread can only do one thing at a time, and it's the compiler's job to figure out how to execute the individual steps you ask for. There's no difference in performance between `int a = getAnInt(); useAnInt(a);` and `getAnInt(useAnInt())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the first line, `output` is basically the equivalent of

```
Pattern.compile("(\\r|\\n|\\t)").matcher(obj).replaceAll("")
```

Because of that, you can replace the variable `output` in the second line with `Pattern.compile("(\\r|\\n|\\t)").matcher(obj).replaceAll("")`. Then the line would become

```
Pattern.compile("[^\\p{Print}]").matcher(Pattern.compile("(\\r|\\n|\\t)").matcher(obj).replaceAll("")).replaceAll(replacement);
```

However, this does not really improve performance, and has a negative impact on readability. Unless you have a really good reason, it would be best to just use the first two lines.

Answer (score 3):

If "efficiency" means "less typing" for you, then the method String.replaceAll("regex", "replacement") might be for you:

```
String output = obj.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\t)", "").replaceAll("[^\\p{Print}]", replacement);
```

You lose the ability to keep the Pattern for reuse, which would actually be more efficient if you have to use it more than once.